# canonical tag and file extensions

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, canonical-link

I was just wondering, I use a `.htaccess` script to strip the file extensions from my `URL's`

Would the canonical tag, which is the direct `URL` you want to user to see contain the file extensions for example;

```
 mysite.co.uk/locations/regions/thislocation.html
```

Example of how my actual url would look;

```
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://mysite.co.uk/locations/regions/thislocation"/>
```

Would the canonical tag be set up with the above URL or with the file extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical URL should represent the URL you want the user to visit (and see in their address bar), not one that only exists as a side-effect of your implementation (the point of it is to *stop* the `.html` version being indexed by search engines).

Answer (score 1):

@anubhava You have to setup a canonical tag without extension.Because google crawls a URL which shows in you Header.

therefore  Link will be : `<link rel="canonical" href="http://mysite.co.uk/locations/regions/thislocation"/>`